# Creating LoadRunner Script to capture Json Data

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a loadrunner 'js' file to capture some data from a json. The json file is located on a web sever, this isn't the issue. I can successfully retrieve the json. However, I would like to return a particular value from the json text. I have attempted to do this on a local html page as follows, but I always get an error message:

> Error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'Location' of undefined

Code:

```
<!doctype html> <head></head><script>

function getdata() 
{
var jsontext = '{"Locations":{"Location":[{"@id":"3649","@latitude":"51.758","@longitude":"-1.576","@country":"England","@zoomLevel":"10","@obsZoomLevel":"5","@type":"Observing Site","@name":"Brize Norton","@geohash":"gcnyknk2h"},{"@id":"3","@latitude":"50.9503","@longitude":"-1.3567","@country":"England","@zoomLevel":"11","@type":"Airport and Heliport","@name":"Southampton    Airport","@geohash":"gcp1c5hp4"}]}}';
var stringifiedjson = JSON.stringify(jsontext).replace(/@/g, '_'); //convert to JSON string
var data = JSON.parse(stringifiedjson);
json.innerHTML=data;

try{
var newlocation0 = data.Locations.Location[1]._id;
output.innerHTML=newlocation0;
return;

}
 catch(err){
    message.innerHTML = "(1)Error is " + err;
}

try{
var newlocation0 = data.Locations.Location[1]._id;
output.innerHTML=newlocation0;
return;
}
 catch(err) {
        message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML + "(2)Error is " + err;
    }

try{
var newlocation0 = data.Locations.Location[0]._id;
output.innerHTML=newlocation0;
return;
}
 catch(err) {
        message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML + "(3)Error is " + err;
    }
}
</script>  
<body>
Error Messages:
<p id="message"></p>
<BR><BR>
JSON Input:
<p id="json"></p>
<BR><BR>
Output:
<p id="output"></p>



<button onclick="getdata()">Check</button> 
<button onclick="location.reload();">Reload</button> 

</body>
```

I have tried different combinations of notations of [0] and [1] but I cannot get an output for the right part of the json.

Comment: Why `var stringifiedjson = JSON.stringify(jsontext)`? This gonna escape all `"` and make your JSON unparsable. After this, if you do a JSON.parse, the output will not be a JS object but only a string. Replace the part `var stringifiedjson = JSON.stringify(jsontext).replace(/@/g, '_');` by `var stringifiedjson = jsontext.replace(/@/g, '_');`

Comment: I've got it working now, thanks for your help! I used stringify as I was under the impression this was the only way to sort out the unruly '@' in the json.

Comment: "LoadRunner," as in the performance testing tool LoadRunner?  If so, there are built in items to handle correlation, the act of capturing data returned from the server to the client.  This would include any type of data within an HTTP stream (or other protocols).  This would also include JSON formatted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsontext is initially a string

```
var jsontext = '{"Locations":{"Location":[{"@id":"3649","@latitude":"51.758","@longitude":"-1.576","@country":"England","@zoomLevel":"10","@obsZoomLevel":"5","@type":"Observing Site","@name":"Brize Norton","@geohash":"gcnyknk2h"},{"@id":"3","@latitude":"50.9503","@longitude":"-1.3567","@country":"England","@zoomLevel":"11","@type":"Airport and Heliport","@name":"Southampton    Airport","@geohash":"gcp1c5hp4"}]}}';
```

you have wrapped that string in another string

```
var stringifiedjson = JSON.stringify(jsontext).replace(/@/g, '_');
```

the resulting string looks like this

```
""{\"Locations\":{\"Location\":[{\"_id\":\"3649\",\"_latitude\":\"51.758\",\"_longitude\":\"-1.576\",\"_country\":\"England\",\"_zoomLevel\":\"10\",\"_obsZoomLevel\":\"5\",\"_type\":\"Observing Site\",\"_name\":\"Brize Norton\",\"_geohash\":\"gcnyknk2h\"},{\"_id\":\"3\",\"_latitude\":\"50.9503\",\"_longitude\":\"-1.3567\",\"_country\":\"England\",\"_zoomLevel\":\"11\",\"_type\":\"Airport and Heliport\",\"_name\":\"Southampton    Airport\",\"_geohash\":\"gcp1c5hp4\"}]}}""
```

parsing once returns the inner JSON string

```
var data = JSON.parse(stringifiedjson);
```

to get the object from string parse again

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

OR

there is no need for JSON.stringify in the first place, you can just use the replace method.

Comment: Will the replace method work as I'm replacing an '@' character. If so how would I do this?

Comment: just do jsontext.replace(/@/g, '_'); instead of JSON.stringify(jsontext).replace(/@/g, '_');  I tried it in the console, it worked for me

Comment: This works as a one-liner `This can actually be a one-liner `testjsonout.innerHTML ="0: " +(JSON.parse(replaceAll(jsontext,'@','_'))).Locations.Location[0]._id;`